# Make post request to Mongodb Atlas using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I was familiar with MongodB for CRUD operation. Here, I'm trying to make simple post request on mongodB atlas but I want to know where I have done error for the connection and posting data to MongodB atlas.

Model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let quizSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: Number,
  },

  question: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Quiz = mongoose.model("Quiz", quizSchema);
module.exports = Quiz;
```

index.js

I'm trying to create the database collection name "QuizDatabase" and insert the data to it.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Quiz = require("./views/model/model");

var Request = require("request");
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.iom1t.mongodb.net/QuizDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connect(uri);


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});

app.post("/new/", function (req, res) {
  Quiz.collection("QuizDatabase").insertMany(req.body, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new quiz.");
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
  });
});
  function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({ error: message });
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It says application error. I am not sure that I am doing post request in correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use mongo client if you are already using mongoose.
In index.js file just import the model

```
const Quiz = require("./model");
```

And you are already using mongoose to connect to db when you write `mongoose.connect(uri);` You don't have to use `client.connect()` again.

Query to insert -

```
Quiz.insertMany(req.body);
```

Your index file should look like this -

```
const Quiz = require("./views/model/model");

var Request = require("request");
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const uri =
"mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.iom1t.mongodb.net/QuizDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(uri);


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});

app.post("/new/", function (req, res) {
  Quiz.insertMany(req.body, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new quiz.");
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
  });
});
  function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({ error: message });
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code according to your suggestion is the way you said ? I'm still getting error could you please check the update code.

Comment: I have updated the answer with code for index file. Please try running that,

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons.

1. Connection Issues to the MongoDB database.

To check this insert app.listen() into mongoose connect. This would make sure you can only run development on your preferred PORT only when it has successfully connected to your Database. e.g From your code

```
mongoose.connect(uri)
  .then(() => {
    //listen for PORT request
    var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Try purposely using the wrong Username or Password and see if you get this error:

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/user/Documents/..<pathway>../connection.js:207:30)
*
*
*
* 
ok: 0,
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError',
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' } }
```

If you don't get this error then you have a connection problem. To solve this, I added my current IP ADDRESS and 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address) at the Network Access page. So you click on MY CURRENT IP ADDRESS and confirm upon setting up the network. Go to NETWORK ACCESS, click on add new IP ADDRESS, input 0.0.0.0/0 and confirm. Then try using the wrong username or password in the URI link given to you to see if it gives the above-expected error, then you can now correct the  Username and Password, and npm run dev or npm start (However you configured it in your package.json file).

2. Code issues

First of I would correct your Model.js file from this:

> const Quiz = mongoose.model("Quiz", quizSchema);
> module.exports = Quiz;

to this:

> module.exports = mongoose.model("Quiz", quizSchema);

I can see why yours can work, but it may be an issue as you want to get the schema upon accessing the whole file.

Secondly, I would correct the code for Posting and you can do that in 2 ways using the asynchronous method. Which depends on the method of assigning the req.body.

Way 1:

```
app.post("/new/", async (req, res) => { 
  const { title, description, question } = req.body;
  //adds doc to db
  try {
    const quiz = await Quiz.create({ title, description, question });
    res.status(200).json(quiz);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

OR

Way2:

```
app.post("/new/", async (req, res) => {
  const quiz = new Quiz(req.body);
  //adds doc to db   
  try {
    const savePost = await quiz.save();
    response.status(200).send(savePost);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send(error);   
  }
});
```

NOTE: You don't necessarily have to create a named database and collection in Mongo Atlas before starting the project. The URI given to you covers that if there are no problems with the connection to the DB or the Code.

based on your code

> URI:
> "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.iom1t.mongodb.net/QuizDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

would create a database called: QuizDatabase and collection called: quizs (MongoDb always creates the plural word from the model given and makes it start with lowercase (i.e from your Model.js, the mongoose.model("Quiz"))).

If no database is named in your URI, then a database called test is automatically created for you as a default database, with the collection name being the mongoose.model("") given.

CONCLUSION

This should solve at least 90% of your issues, any other creation/POST problems is currently beyond my current expertise. Happy Coding